# Is there a way to write Redis.OM query with multiple aggregations?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to have multiple aggregations for redis via Redis.OM in one call. Something like this code for EF provider:

```
var efGroup = from props in efquery
group props by props.State into grp
select new
{
    PriceSum = grp.Sum(cc => cc.Price),
    PriceAvg = grp.Average(c => c.Price),
    SizeAvg = grp.Average(c => c.Size)
};
```

On the [redis tutorial page](https://developer.redis.com/develop/dotnet/redis-om-dotnet/aggregations/groups/groups) there is an example how to do aggregation with grouping

```
var employeeAggregations = provider.AggregationSet<Employee>();
var departments = employeeAggregations.GroupBy(x=>x.RecordShell.Department).Sum(x=>x.RecordShell.Sales);
```

I tried to add additional calls to that:

```
var agr = redisAggr.GroupBy(x => x.RecordShell.State)
    .Sum(x => x.RecordShell.Salary)
    .Average(x => x.RecordShell.Age)
    .ToList();
```

but that just throws the `Property 'Age' not present in document or pipeline`.

I was also trying to do the similar query as for EF, but that just throws `Timeout performing UNKNOWN (5000ms)`

**Is there a way to have sums/avg/count in one go for many fields?**

Comment: This was a bug in Redis OM .NET, should be fixed by v0.1.6

Comment: thanks for the update @slorello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As slorello wrote, it's fixed since 0.1.6.
Thanks.